# Should a method modifying object passed as a parameter return the modified object?

Tags: java, readability, parameters, mutable, out-parameters

I have some incoming request - it's an instance of class generated from api specification - POJO with public getters/setters.
I would like to normalize some values. For example dimensions (to use metric system).

I have a service class which has method processing incoming requests. First I would like to normalize the request.

So I define the method like:

```
private void normalizeDimensions(Request request);
```

and inside I normalize request's fields related to dimensions.

But from the readability perspective I think it's better to return the modified object so it's more explicit that something was changed and ideally the caller should use the returned object:

```
private Request normalizeDimensions(Request request);
```

What do you think is better from readability perspective or generally?

Comment: Does this mean that all Request properties are public?

Comment: @Christophe yes, I modified the question.

Comment: Here is pretty the same question [Coding style issue: Should we have functions which take a parameter, modify it, and then RETURN that parameter?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262221/coding-style-issue-should-we-have-functions-which-take-a-parameter-modify-it?rq=1). But in my case the object to modify is a generated POJO.

Comment: @Shaolin: note my answer to that other question which I posted a link above - even when you here use a non-member function, my arguments against this style stay exactly the same - you create the opposite effect of what you are trying to accomplish. And Philip Kendall's answer is telling you almost the same.

Comment: @DocBrown I find your answer helpful and I used it to mark my question as a duplicate. But I think that this question should be duplicate of [Coding style issue: Should we have functions which take a parameter, modify it, and then RETURN that parameter?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262221/coding-style-issue-should-we-have-functions-which-take-a-parameter-modify-it?rq=1). My opinion is that it answers my question slightly better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have this backwards. The *only* thing that

```java
private void normalizeDimensions(Request request);
```

can do is to modify the object (or have other side effects), so it's clear that's what this function *must* do.

```java
private Request normalizeDimensions(Request request);
```

implies to me that it returns a new `Request` object and does not modify the original object.

But then I come from a functional world where objects are immutable so the idea of modifying an object doesn't exist.

Comment: sorry, but there is no implication that the object won't be changed in the second approach. Method chaining and fluent interfaces are still popular. A prefix convention would be advised (such as `with` to tell that the original value doesn't change: https://blog.joda.org/2011/08/common-java-method-names.html?m=1 )

Answer (score 2):

In the functional world Philip Kendall is entirely correct. And in the OOP world we occasionally write functional code as well. So if you're going to make `Request` immutable then:

```java
private Request normalizeDimensions(Request request);
```

This makes me expect a modified defensive copy of the immutable request. Even in the OOP world.

But if your `Request` is mutable then in the OOP world it would look like this:

```java
public void normalizeDimensions();
```

and you'd call it like this:

```java
request.normalizeDimensions();
```

Because in the OOP world, objects suck up the methods that act on them.

---

Now if `Request` is big and ugly and you'd like it to be immutable anyway another OOP trick (at least in the Java world) is the [Joshua Bloch Builder](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2):

```java
public RequestBuilder normalizeDimensions();
```

Which would be used like this:

```java
Request request = new Request
    .Builder("Stuff")
    .otherStuff("stuffy")
    .normalizeDimensions()
    .build()
;
```

Done this way you get one chance to normalize those dimensions on the builder before it spits out the immutable request.

This is mostly a Java thing because those lucky C# coders have [named arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) which is what Joshua is helping us simulate here.